# Database connection works locally but fails when published to server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working on a ASP.net website, I have everything working and wanted to deploy it to the server which is goDaddy to test the changes I made. I have had this code, the exact same project with the identical database connection string and calls on the server before. Nothing changed really I just changed one method in a class which has nothing to do with the database at all. I have the code trust set to full so the code should have permission to connect. When I set the code trust lower then full it will give me an error that I don't have the needed permissions so I'm sure this isn't where the problem lays.

Like the title says when I try the code on my local environement everything works just fine. When I try to do the same thing on the server I get a message saying:

"unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"
when you go to http://test.ceremoniecompleet.nl/admin and try to log in you will get the error. When I try to login locally it works just fine.

The connection string I'm using is as follows

```
con.ConnectionString = "server=188.121.44.188; database=CeremonieCompleet_DB; uid=CCU; pwd=mypassword;";
```

I've tried to use `188.121.44.188:3306` but this doesn't work at all. One of the godaddy support people suggested using this but this just fails on both locally and the server.

does anyone have any clue what could be going on?
the only thing that changed really is that I used visual studio 2012 before and now I'm using visual studio 2015 because my pc needed a completely fresh install.

**EDIT:**

Currently the mysql.data.dll that I added to the project is version 6.0.3.0 could it be that this just needs an upgrade?

Comment: You can try turn off server firewall, or show `Raw error message` when try connect to mySql server.

Comment: just to confirm are you using mysql?

Comment: yes I am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

The 188.121.44.188 is the godaddy server?
If it is, try changing to 'localhost'.
If it isn't, try to create a database in godaddy and set the server to 'localhost'.

To set the port, you need this string "server=<>; port=3306; ..."

Comment: Yeah it is the godaddy database address. I tried changing it to localhost but it doesn't change anything. I tried setting the port like you suggested. It will work locally but again fail on the godaddy server.